# Adjusting the UIButton Font in custom cell when the screen changes using autolayout

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uibutton, uistoryboard, custom-cell

I have an UIButton in the custom cell of UITableview which is at the bottom of the screen so is it possible to adjust the font size of the UIButton title as the screen changes? Currently i am facing the following issue. The title gets cut when comes in iPhone 5s. How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps in your Storyboard or nib file.

- Select your button.
- Then you can go to your attributes Inspector tab, you will notice that there is a "+" in front of font, click it to add font for different device variation.
- Select different font size for different variation.

**Hope it will help you. :)**

Comment: How to add variation for different screens particularly for 5s and SE

Comment: compact width, regular height: iPhones in Portrait

Comment: For more detail check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381273/size-classes-to-distinguish-between-iphone-5-6-and-6-plus

Comment: My Answer is not particularly for iphone 5s and SE. If you are facing issue only for particular devices for that first you need to get device name then update font size accordingly.